# Find the sum of all the number formed by 2,4,6, and 8 without repetition.Number may be of any digit like 2, 24, 684, 4862.

Tags: general-topology

> Find the sum of all the number formed by 2,4,6, and 8 without repetition.Number may be of any digit like 2, 24, 684, 4862.

My Approach:

single digit no formed = 2,4,6,8

sum= 2+4+6+8= 20

two digit= 24,26,28,42,46,48,62,64,68,82,84,86

sum= 660

three digit no=246+264+426+462+624+642=2664

268+286+628+682+826+862=3552

248+284+428+482+824+842=3108

468+486+648+684+846+864=3996

sum of all 3 digit nos =13310

Similarly for all 4 digit numbers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are:

- four $1$-digit numbers, whose average is $5$: sum = $20$
- twelve $2$-digit numbers, whose average is $55$: sum = $660$
- twenty-four $3$-digit numbers, whose average is $555$: sum = $13320$
- twenty-four $4$-digit numbers, whose average is $5555$: sum = $133320$

To see why these averages are correct, you can pair off each number uniquely with its 'complement' obtained by exchanging $2$ with $8$ and $4$ with $6$. The average of each of these pairs is $5\dots5$.

Comment: This solution is missing why there are 4/12/24/24 numbers with 1/2/3/4 digits. Some mentioning to $\frac{4!}{(4-i)!}$ and why it is so.

Comment: @Timbo: Feel free to post your own answer. This is how I chose to post mine $-$ I think interested readers can work such details out for themselves.

Comment: @Timbo  u added this part which is missing but how u get this?please explain in detail.

Comment: @TonyK i was actually left speechless after seeing this mathematical brilliance but except for the clear patterns of averages (5,55,555,5555) i find the sums (20,660,13320,133320) following a neat pattern also...is it so?? Do you know what it is..??

Answer (score 10):

To sum all the numbers with four digits, note that for any given digit in any given position, it appears in the sum six times. That is, for example, there are six ways to complete a number if we know that its third digit is $4$. Then, the sum is
$$6(2222+4444+6666+8888)=6(2+4+6+8)1111$$

Comment: How  6?Could not note that point.could u explain that point in detail a bit?

Comment: @justintakro Whatever the first digit is, there are 3 remaining choices for the second digit, 2 for the third, and 1 choice left for the last.

Comment: @Mike why whatever first digit?It can be arranged in 4 ways,then 3 ways for second digit then 2 ways for 3rd  and then 1 way for last.

Comment: @justintakro For example, try to figure out how many 4 digit numbers have an 8 as the first digit.  There are 6 permutations for the remaining digits, so an 8 in the first digit needs to be added in 6 times.  That's where the 6 comes in.  The same logic applies for calculating how many 4 digit numbers have an 8 as the second, third, or fourth digit, which is where the 8888 comes from.  Ditto for choosing something other than 8.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this might help.

sum of number by taking $n$ digits all at a time $= (n-1!)(x_1+ x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_n)$

so if we want to find the sum of all the number formed by $2,4,6$ and $8$ without repetition, "without repetition".
[
  ( 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 )( 3! ) = 120.
]
Now multiply this with the place values = $120 ( 10^0 + 10^1 + 10^2 + 10^3 )$

if we want to find the sum of all the number formed by $2,4,6$ and $8$ without repetition, "with repetition", then

$( 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 )( 4*4*4 )$ (keeping $2$ at units place _ _ _ $2$), and the next step is same.

Comment: Please format using MathJax

Answer (score 0):

Simple formula :- (n-1)! * Sum of digits * 1111 n times.
That is, (4-1)! * (2+4+6+8)* 1111
= 6*20*1111
= 1,33,320

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score -1):

Consider an example by taking digits as $3,4,6,8$.
total combinations possible$=4\times 3\times 2=24$ numbers possible
no of digits$=4$
hence $\dfrac{24}{4}$ each digit comes $6$ times in ones, tens and hundred's place
at ones place=$6\times (3+4+6+8)=126\equiv6$.
at ten's place$=6\times (3+4+6+8)+12(\text{carry})=138\equiv 8$.
At hundred's place$=6\times (3+4+6+8)=139\equiv 9$
so, $3$ will come at thousands place and $1$ at ten thousands place,
Hence, the number is $139864$.